# Can I automatically set the AssemblyVersion in a Visual Studio proj file prior to a build?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, versioning

Can I write a script that reads a text file and writes a value to the proj file of my app in Visual Studio prior to a Build?

Specifically before a build I'd like to read a value from a simple text file in my solution and write it to the AssemblyVersion in the .csproj folder.
    1.0.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a version from the file could perform via [ReadLinesFromFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/readlinesfromfile-task) built-in task.

---

**.NET Framework**:

When a version has been got it's need to pass it to the custom target:

```
<Target Name="EntryVersion" BeforeTargets="Build">

    <Message Text="-----Entry-----" Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text=" Write Version " Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="-----Entry-----" Importance="high"/>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Assembly Include="AssemblyProduct"><_Parameter1>$(Product)</_Parameter1></Assembly>
        <Assembly Include="AssemblyCompany"><_Parameter1>$(Company)</_Parameter1></Assembly>
        <Assembly Include="AssemblyVersion"><_Parameter1>$(Version)</_Parameter1></Assembly>
    </ItemGroup>

    <WriteCodeFragment AssemblyAttributes="@(Assembly)" Language="C#" OutputFile="..\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs"/>
</Target>
```

This snippet generates the source file that will contain the assembly attributes. Besides, the output file must be included in the projects as a link, the used attributes must be removed from `AssemblyInfo`.

---

**.NET Core | Standard**:

It's possible to use native property `Version` from `MSBuild CLI` or override it from the custom target. The value is automatically will be added to the assembly attribute.

---

If you use `ApplicationVersion` from `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions`, then see [Issue 237](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/237).

---

[ReadLinesFromFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/readlinesfromfile-task) | [WriteCodeFragment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/writecodefragment-task) | [Exec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task)

Comment: This is a good start--thanks.  I'm not very familiar with MsBuild at all, so it's slow going for me.  I'm able to read in my value from the external file to a variable, then write it out to the GlobalAssemblyInfo file.  I included the GlobalAssemblyFile in my project.  Only problem I have is when I then dump Application.ApplicationVersion it doesn't show that value.

Comment: @MatthewAllen, Application.ApplicationVersion this property is from `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions`? If yes, then see: [Issue 237](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/237) may be it help.

Comment: yeah, I'm using the ApplicationConfig in those extensions.  Stuck in .Net Core 1.1 for now, but hopefully able to migrate to 2.x soon.  I'll just stub in the new calls now--thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @MatthewAllen, In `.NET Core` case you can use native property `Version` via `MSBuild CLI` without any `GlobalAssemblyInfo` files.

Comment: @MatthewAllen, did it help you? Or do you still have problems?

Comment: @MatthewAllen, if the post is the answer to your question, then you can accept it.